How to display benchmark for each product in this stacked column chart?
See example data and chart below. I want to display the benchmark for each region on its corresponding column. How do I go about this? I have tried plotting the benchmarks on the secondary axis and using shaders to display benchmarks (but this causes issues if the benchmark < actual sales) so this didn't work. Any ideas on how best to visualize this data?
I don't want to overlay a line graph, but more so a dash or a line above each column to indicate where the benchmark is for each product / region.
Thank you!


First of all, it's a clustered column chart. No matter.
So create your chart from the data (Chart 1). Format the benchmarks with a colored border and no fill, and the actuals with the same color, but with 50% transparency and no border (Chart 2). Assign the actuals to the secondary axis, then delete the secondary axis (Chart 3). If desired, fiddle with the primary and secondary axis gap width and overlap (Chart 4; primary overlap -10%, gap width 50%; secondary overlap -50%, gap width 110%)


Jon Sir superb looks amazing!

Thanks @Jon, that looks exactly how I want it to. Much appreciated!!
